# Monitoring option not present under app settings in AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, amplifyjs, aws-amplify-cli

I have an AWS amplify backend where i have configured AUTH and API. I want to add monitoring now and I am following the below guide from AWS.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/access-logs.html

It clearly says that Monitoring option is under App Settings. But in my AWS Amplify there is just General and ADMIN UI Management options are present, not monitoring. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok So first you have to connect your frontend environment with a frontend code and then it will appear.